# how to get postgres docker container to initialize with scram-sha-256 on any connection?

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers

I’m trying to set a **POSTGRES_USER** & **POSTGRES_PASSWORD** with a docker postgres configuration using `pg_hba.conf` & `postgresql.conf` files:

```
docker run --name pg \
-e POSTGRES_USER=myUser \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myPassword \
-e POSTGRES_DB=myDb \
-v $PWD/pg_hba.conf:/etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf \
-v $PWD/postgresql.conf:/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf \
--network data-talk \
-d postgres \
-c config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf \
-c hba_file=/etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf
```

```sh
pg_hba.conf

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    all             all             172.19.0.0/16           scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

```sh
postgresql.conf

listen_addresses = '*'
password_encryption = 'scram-sha-256'       # md5 or scram-sha-256
```

From here https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

> **Note 1:** The PostgreSQL image sets up `trust` authentication locally so you may notice a password is not required when connecting from `localhost` (inside the same container). However, a password will be required if connecting from a different host/container.

I want to require a password on any/every connection including local. By changing the `pg_hba.conf` I thought I could fulfill this request. I am using `172.19.0.0/16` as this is the subnet for the docker network.

When I run the above docker command I check the logs to find this `psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user “myUser”`.

Any idea on how to get this to work? I’ve also tried

```
docker run --name pg \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password \
-v $PWD/pg_hba.conf:/etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf \
-v $PWD/postgresql.conf:/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf \
--network data-talk \
-d postgres \
-c config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf \
-c hba_file=/etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf
```

which runs to completion but errors when I try to login locally:

```
$ docker exec -it pg sh
psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following along here https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/12/docker-entrypoint.sh#L202 I assume that on first run and setting up the database the authentication method is `md5` , and when it is done the `pg_hba.conf` file sets it to `scram-sha-256` making it unable to authenticate.

By setting the `POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS` and passing along the params to set the initial auth method to `scram-sha-256` the password is set with `scram-sha-256` for the initialization of the db, and just works.

```sql
docker run --name pg \
-e POSTGRES_USER=myUser \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myPassword \
-e POSTGRES_DB=myDb \
-e POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS="--auth-host=scram-sha-256 --auth-local=scram-sha-256" \
-v $PWD/pg_hba.conf:/etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf \
-v $PWD/postgresql.conf:/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf \
--network data-talk \
-d postgres \
-c config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf \
-c hba_file=/etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf
```

#### `POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS`

> This optional environment variable can be used to send arguments to `postgres initdb`. The value is a space separated string of arguments as postgres initdb would expect them. This is useful for adding functionality like data page checksums: -e POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS="--data-checksums"

The key here is on `initdb`

Answer (score 0):

What is missing is that there are no passwords set for the users initially, so you have locked yourself out with that `pg_hba.conf`.

You need to start the PostgreSQL server and set a password for the `postgres` superuser. If you want to live securely, you'd also have to create at least one non-superuser that has a password.

The easiest way to do that is probably to start PostgreSQL in single-user mode with the option `--single` (see the documentation for details). That has the advantage that `pg_hba.conf` is ignored, and you are automatically connected as the bootstrap superuser.